# Correct annotation to train spaCy's NER

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition, information-extraction

I'm having some troubles finding the right way how to annotate my data. I'm dealing with laboratory test related texts and I am using the following labels:

***1) Test specification*** (e.g. voltage, length,...)

***2) Test object*** (e.g. battery, steal beam,...)

***3) Test value*** (e.g.  5 V; 5 m...)

Let's take this example sentences:

*The battery voltage should be 5 V.*

I would annotate this sentences like this:

```
The
battery voltage (test specification)
should
be
5 V (Test value)
.
```

However, if this sentences looks like this:

*The voltage of the battery should be 5 V.*

I would use the following annotation:

```
The
voltage (Test specification)
of
the
battery (Test object)
should
be
5 V (Test value)
.
```

Is anyone experienced in annotating data to explain if this is the right way? Or should I use in he first example the Test object label for *battery* as well? Or should I combine the labels in the second example *voltage of the battery* as Test specification?

I am annotating the data to perform information extraction.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

All of your examples are unusual annotations formats. The typical way to tag NER data (in text) is to use an IOB/BILOU format, where each token is on one line, the file is a TSV, and one of the columns is a label. So for your data it would look like:

```
The
voltage U-SPEC
of
the
battery U-OBJ
should
be
5 B-VALUE
V L-VALUE
.
```

Pretend that is TSV, and I have omitted O tags, which are used for "other" items.

You can find documentation of these schema in [the spaCy docs](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#iob).

If you already have data in the format you provided, or you find it easier to make it that way, it should be easy to convert at least. For training NER spaCy requires the data be provided in a particular format, see [the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-train-ner) for details, but basically you need the input text, character spans, and the labels of those spans. Here's example data:

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [(7, 17, "PERSON")]}),
    ("I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": [(7, 13, "LOC"), (18, 24, "LOC")]}),
]
```

This format is trickier to produce manually than the above TSV type format, so generally you would produce the TSV-like format, possibly using a tool, and then convert it.

Answer (score 0):

The main rule to correctly annotate entities is to be consistent (i.e. you always apply the same rules when deciding which entity is what). I can see you already khave some rules in terms of when `battery` `voltage` should be considered `test object` or `test specification`.
Apply those rules consistently and you'll be ok.

Have a look at the [spacy-annotator](https://github.com/ieriii/spacy-annotator).
It is a library that helps you annotating data in the way you want.
Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from spacy_annotator.pandas_annotations import annotate as pd_annotate

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'full_text' : [The battery voltage should be 5 V., 'The voltage of the battery should be 5 V.']})

# Annotations
pd_dd = pd_annotate(df,
            col_text = 'full_text',     # Column in pandas dataframe containing text to be labelled
            labels = ['test_specification', 'test object', 'test_value'], # List of labels
            sample_size=1,              # Size of the sample to be labelled
            delimiter=',',              # Delimiter to separate entities in GUI
            model = None,               # spaCy model for noisy pre-labelling
            regex_flags=re.IGNORECASE   # One (or more) regex flags to be applied when searching for entities in text
            )

# Example output
pd_dd['annotations'][0]
```

The code will show you a user interface you can use to annotate each relevant entities.